# War file deployment failed in jboss eap 6.4

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am new to JBoss EAP 6.4. I have an application which builds successfully on Maven. I then deploy the war file manually in EAP-6.4.0/standalone/deployments folder and start the JBoss server in bin/standalone.bat.In WEB-INF folder I have a dispatcher-servlet.xml, hibernate-cfg.xml and web.xml The war deployment fails, and I get the following error:

```
MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./myProject: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./omoto: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    ... 6 more
```

my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>omoto</groupId>
    <artifactId>omoto</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>omoto</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlcleaner</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlparser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.Final</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-driver</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
                            <name>mysql.jar</name>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```